# Problem to deploy a node / express API using now.sh

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a node / express API that has several endpoints for use at now.sh.

My question is how to correctly configure the file now.json.

leave the image where you can see the complete structure of the project, the main path would be the ./src/ where are all the folders and files.

The main entrypoint is `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/` for localhost

I delete the file now.json and from the terminal I paste the `now` command, and then I generated the deployment in the following path

`https://ryuanime.chrismichael.now.sh`

But when I try to go to `https://ryuanime.chrismichael.now.sh/api/v1` it shows me `404: NOT_FOUND`

**Image**

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8lGU.jpg)

**now.json**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "ryuanime",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/index.ts",
      "use": "@now/node-server"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [{"src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/src/index.ts"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it worked by referring to

```
"src": "./src/index.ts"
```

and not

```
"src": "src / index.ts",
```

```
{
  "name": "ryuanime-api",
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./src/index.ts",
      "use": "@now/node-server"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/src/index.ts" }
  ]
}
```